# Centering two cols with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering how can I center on the page two cols with bootstrap. What I mean I have this:

```
<header>
  ....
</header>
<section id="main" role="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-7">
          <div class="main-wrap">
             ....
          </div>
       </div>
       <aside class="col-sm-3">
          ....
        </aside>   
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want to center the `<section>...</section>` under the header.

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/706bcaxn/2/). So the section main which contain image and search form (left and right side) must be centered on header. Is it possible?

Comment: As an aside, your sectioning elements should have a heading, otherwise it is better to use generic containers instead.

Comment: It's have I just removed them for the demo on jsfiddle. Thank's for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap has built in classes to offset the column on the grid.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

```
col-sm-offset-1
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/706bcaxn/8/

Comment: Ah, I'm sort of new in bootstrap and still learning. Didn't know about offsets. Thank's this work great!